# Construtores sobrecarregados: Inicializador de Instância

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, método, certificado-digital

Do ponto de vista do comportamento do compilador e java class design qual seria a justificativa de usar o bloco Inicializador de Instância?

Considerando a seguinte classe:

```
class Caneta {
    public Caneta() {
        System.out.println("Caneta:constructor");
    }
    public Caneta(String a) {
        System.out.println("Caneta:constructor2");
    } 

    /** ################################### */
    /** Inicializador de Instância */
    /** ################################### */
    {
        System.out.println("Caneta:init1");
    }
    
    /** ################################### */
    /** Inicializador de Instância */
    /** ################################### */
    {
        System.out.println("Caneta:init2");
    }
    /** ################################### */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Caneta();
        new Caneta("aValue");
    }
}
```

A saída do código anterior é:

```
Caneta:init1
Caneta:init2
Caneta:constructor
Caneta:init1
Caneta:init2
Caneta:constructor2
```

Por que você acha que precisa de um inicializador de instância se você pode inicializar suas instâncias usando construtores?

#### Referência:

[MALA GUPTA, 2015], **OCP Java SE 7 Programmer II

 Certification Guide**: PREPARE FOR THE 1ZO-804 EXAM

Comment: @TiagoS, as duas perguntas foi eu quem fez e são diferentes. Uma pergunta sobre o comportamento dos métodos sobrecarregados e a outra pergunta sobre o uso Inicializador de Instância do ponto de vista de compilação e java class design. Não são duplicatas!

Answer (score 2):

Esta é uma boa explicação:

> Inicializadores de instância são alternativas úteis aos inicializador de variável de instância quando:
>
> - O código de inicialização deve capturar exceções;
> - Realizar cálculos extensos que não podem ser representados com um inicializador de variável de instância.
>
> Você pode, obviamente, sempre escrever tal código em construtores.
>   Porém, numa classe que tem múltiplos construtores, você repetiria o código em cada construtor. Com esta alternativa, você pode escrever o código apenas uma vez, e ele será executado independente de qual construtor é usado para construir o objeto. Eles também são úteis in inner class anônimas, as quais não podem declarar um construtor.
>
> Estes inicializadores (assim como os de variável) não podem fazer referência a variáveis declaradas textualmente depois no código. Quando um objeto é criado, os inicializadores são executados em ordem textual - sua ordem de aparência no código fonte. Essa regra ajuda a impedir que os inicializadores usem variáveis de instância que ainda não tenham sido inicializadas corretamente.

Fonte: JavaWorld [Object initialization in Java](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-03-1998/jw-03-initialization.html?page=4).

Comment: Para ficar registrado: não é necessário repetir o código em cada construtor, dá pra um construtor chamar o outro com `this();`

Comment: @MurilloGoulart, vc não considerou que inicializadores não podem fazer referência de variáveis. *JavaWorld* [Object initialization in Java](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-03-1998/jw-03-initialization.html?page=4): Quando um objeto é criado, os inicializadores são executados em ordem textual - sua ordem de aparência no código-fonte. Essa regra ajuda a impedir que os inicializadores usem variáveis de instância que ainda não tenham sido inicializadas corretamente. Se possível, vc pode melhorar a sua resposta?

Comment: @pss1suporte Esta regra não é exclusiva para este tipo de inicializador. Ela vale para inicializadores de variáveis também. Mesmo assim, adicionei.

Comment: @MurilloGoulart, isso mesmo. Verdade, mas o objetivo é quanto mais completa melhor a resposta. Eu gostaria de saber disso ao usar os blocos de Inicializador de Instância. É uma informação relevante. Muito obrigado!